# Beautiful soup get text from Id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to catch the text of an id with BeautifulSoup. The result should be 30,66.

My actual code print the complete span element:

```
[<span class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue">30,66</span>]
```

How do I get just the value 30,66?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u = '<div class="widgetBox" data-name="pvEnergy"><div class="widgetHead">PV-Energie</div><div class="widgetBody"><div class="mainValue"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue" class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit">30,66</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldUnit" class="mainValueUnit">kWh</span><br><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldPeriodTitle" class="mainValueDescription">Heute</span></div></div><div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalDiv" class="widgetFooter">Gesamt:&nbsp;<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalValue">158,953</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalUnit">MWh</span></div></div>'

idAktWert = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue'

soup = BeautifulSoup(u, "html.parser")

aktWert = soup.select("#" + idAktWert)

print(aktWert)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: soup.select function returns a list of selected elements. Hence the above prints  the selected objects list. to retrieve just the text inside the tag,  text property can be accessed for the selected object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u = '<div class="widgetBox" data-name="pvEnergy"><div class="widgetHead">PV-Energie</div><div class="widgetBody"><div class="mainValue"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue" class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit">30,66</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldUnit" class="mainValueUnit">kWh</span><br><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldPeriodTitle" class="mainValueDescription">Heute</span></div></div><div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalDiv" class="widgetFooter">Gesamt:&nbsp;<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalValue">158,953</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalUnit">MWh</span></div></div>'
idAktWert = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue'
soup = BeautifulSoup(u, "html.parser")
aktWert = soup.select("#" + idAktWert)[0]    #Note: I have used Index to select the first element in list. 
print(aktWert.text)
```

**Output:**

```
30,66
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need `get_text()` for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u = '<div class="widgetBox" data-name="pvEnergy"><div class="widgetHead">PV-Energie</div><div class="widgetBody"><div class="mainValue"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue" class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit">30,66</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldUnit" class="mainValueUnit">kWh</span><br><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldPeriodTitle" class="mainValueDescription">Heute</span></div></div><div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalDiv" class="widgetFooter">Gesamt:&nbsp;<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalValue">158,953</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldTotalUnit">MWh</span></div></div>'

idAktWert = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue'

soup = BeautifulSoup(u, "html.parser")

aktWert = soup.select("#" + idAktWert)
// since aktWert is an array, we need to get the 1st index
print(aktWert[0].get_text()) // outputs 30,66
```